# Authorization token from servlet filter stores user name

Tags: java, authentication, session, servlets, jsp

I'm having some difficulty with servlet and filter lifecycles.  The intention here is to use the [front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) with a simple login; authentication is accomplished with the filter.

Am I passing the `auth` token in a rational way?

The `login.jsp` page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="${sessionScope.auth.duke}"> 
        my name is ${requestScope.controller.myName}, ${requestScope.controller.myId}, what's yours?
        <form name="user_name_form" action="controller" method="POST">
            login: <input type="text" name="login" value="" size='20' />
            <p>
                <input type="submit">
            </p>
        </form>
        ${sessionScope.auth.greeting}
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The filter (as bare-bones as possible):

```
package net.bounceme.dur.webapp.filter;

import net.bounceme.dur.webapp.tokens.AuthenticationToken;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@WebFilter(
        filterName = "authenticationFilter",
        description = "authentication",
        urlPatterns = "/*",
        initParams = {
            @WebInitParam(name = "1", value = "bart"),
            @WebInitParam(name = "2", value = "homer")})

public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class.getName());
    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;
    private final Map<String, String> mapOfUsers = new HashMap<>();
    private final AuthenticationToken token = new AuthenticationToken();
    private final String className = AuthenticationFilter.class.getName();
    private Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean auth = false;
    private String contextPath;

    public AuthenticationFilter() {
    }

    private void doBeforeProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.fine("do before processing..");  //init?
    }

    private void doAfterProcessing(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.fine("do after processing");  //add image here?
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info(className + "do filter..");
        token.setToken((HttpServletRequest) request);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        log.info(className + "..do filter");
    }

    public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
        return (this.filterConfig);
    }

    public void setFilterConfig(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        log.info(className + "\tinit..");
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
        if (filterConfig != null) {
            log.fine("SessionCheckFilter:Initializing filter");
        } else {
            log.warning("null filterConfig");
        }
        String context = filterConfig.getServletContext().getServletContextName();
        String path = filterConfig.getServletContext().getContextPath();
        contextPath = "http://localhost:8080" + context + path;
        String duke = contextPath + "/duke.gif";
        token.setDuke(duke);
        token.initFilterConfig(filterConfig);
        log.info(token.toString());
        log.info(className + "\t..init");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return token.toString();
    }

    private void sendProcessingError(Throwable t, ServletResponse response) {
        log.fine("send processing error");
        String stackTrace = getStackTrace(t);

        if (stackTrace != null && !stackTrace.equals("")) {
            try {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream()); PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ps)) {
                    pw.print("<html>\n<head>\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n"); //NOI18N
                    pw.print("<h1>The resource did not process correctly</h1>\n<pre>\n");
                    pw.print(stackTrace);
                    pw.print("</pre></body>\n</html>"); //NOI18N
                }
                response.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
                    t.printStackTrace(ps);
                }
                response.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getStackTrace(Throwable t) {
        String stackTrace = null;
        try {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            t.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.close();
            sw.close();
            stackTrace = sw.getBuffer().toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        log.warning(stackTrace);
        return stackTrace;
    }

}
```

The token (as heavy as possible):

```
package net.bounceme.dur.webapp.tokens;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class AuthenticationToken implements MyToken {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationToken.class.getName());
    private Map<String, MyRoles> mapOfUsers;
    private String duke = "duke..";
    private String login = "nemo";
    private String className = AuthenticationToken.class.getName();
    private boolean auth = false;
    private String greeting = "";
    private Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    private String contextPath;

    public AuthenticationToken() {  //would like to make private
        log.info(AuthenticationToken.class.getName() + "\tnew..");
    }

    public void initFilterConfig(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        log.info(className + "\tinitFilterConfig..");
        Enumeration parameterNames = filterConfig.getInitParameterNames();
        users = new HashMap<>();  //?
        String name = null;
        String val = null;
        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            name = parameterNames.nextElement().toString();
            val = filterConfig.getInitParameter(name);
            users.put(name, val);
        }
        log.info(className + "\n" + users);
        log.info(className + "\t..initFilterConfig");
    }

    private void initParams(HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info(className + "\tinitParams..");
        parameters = new HashMap<>();  //?
        Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
        String name = null;
        String val = null;
        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
            name = params.nextElement();
            val = request.getParameter(name);
            parameters.put(name, val);
        }
        log.info(className + "\n" + parameters);
        log.info(className + "\t..initParams");
    }

    public void setToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info(className + "\tsetToken..");
        initParams(request);
        String login = null;
        if (parameters.containsKey("login")) {
            login = parameters.get("login").toLowerCase();
            setLogin(login);
            if (users.containsValue(login)) {
                auth = true;
                setGreeting("welcome " + login + " you've been authorized.");
                String image = contextPath + "/" + login + ".gif";
            } else {
                auth = false;
                setGreeting("welcome " + login);
                String image = contextPath + "/duke.gif";
            }
        } else {
            auth = false;
            String image = contextPath + "/duke.gif";
        }
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.setAttribute("auth", this); //??
        }
        log.info(toString());
        log.info(className + "\t..setToken");
    }

    public String getDuke() {
        return duke;
    }

    public void setDuke(String duke) {
        this.duke = duke;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public boolean isAuth() {
        return auth;
    }

    public void setAuth(boolean auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return duke;
    }

}
```

(The only reason all users get the duke gif is because I was having trouble copying gif's into the web folder...I'll fix that down the road.  Each user will have their own gif:  bart.gif, homer.gif, etc.)

full code:   [https://github.com/THUFIR/WebApplication](https://github.com/THUFIR/WebApplication/tree/4b9eaec82243709360788c2dc5e7ef2603b042ad)